# Converting Python dictionary to list, sequence error value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, dtmf

There is .mat file that I have to read and plot its spectogram. When I read content from file I get dictionary and then have to convert it to list. Converting is done in simple for loop (as it shows in code down). There is error in signal.stft function which ends with "
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence". So what did I miss and could anyone help me with this code.

```
Fs = 8000
dtmf = sio.loadmat('dtmf1.mat')
dictlist = []

for key, value in dtmf.items():
    temp = [key,value]
    dictlist.append(temp)

f1, t1, Zxx1 = signal.stft(dictlist, Fs, nperseg=512,
                           window=signal.hamming(512), 
                           noverlap=512, boundary='even')

plt.figure()
plt.pcolormesh(t1, f1, 20*np.log10(np.abs(Zxx1)))
plt.xlabel('Time [s]')
plt.ylabel('Freq [Hz]')$
```

Comment: please show us the file input dtmf1.mat and also how you define signal and sio. thanks.

Comment: dictlist is a list of lists `[[k,v],[k,v]]` . I have no idea if that is OK for the function call : `signal.stft(...)`

Answer (score 0):

What I should do is

```
dictlist = dtmf['dtmf1']
```

instead of

```
for key, value in dtmf.items():
temp = [key,value]
dictlist.append(temp)
```

because there are redudant keys (all except 'dtmf1') in dictionary for my application.

Anyway, thank you a lot âńōŋŷXmoůŜ and balderman.